# Shifting DatetimeIndex by one year gives unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a `DatetimeIndex` and would like to shift the dates by one year. I thought I could do so with `df.index.shift(1, 'Y')`, but then all dates pile up at the end of the year?

What I mean is this (using the [example from the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
month_starts = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='MS')
print("Original:", month_starts)
print("Shifted :", month_starts.shift(1, 'Y'))
```

This code creates a `DatetimeIndex` with 5 dates and shifts these by one year. However, the output is

```
Original: DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01', '2011-02-01', '2011-03-01', '2011-04-01',
              '2011-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
Shifted : DatetimeIndex(['2011-12-31', '2011-12-31', '2011-12-31', '2011-12-31',
              '2011-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

The desired result of the shift would have been `['2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01', '2012-05-01']`. Am I misunderstanding what the function is supposed to do?

Comments:

- The output of `month_starts.shift(365, 'D'))` is closer to the desired result, but not quite there because 2012 is a leap year.
- `pd.__version__`: `1.3.0`

Answer (score 4):

You could use DateOffset as `freq`:

```
month_starts.shift(freq = pd.DateOffset(years = 1))
```

Gives:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01',
              '2012-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Note:**

Use with caution. Leap day (Feb 29th) will be transformed into Feb 28th (as per comments).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution. Do you have any insight why `shift` does not return this?

Comment: No worries. No, unfortunately I'm just as puzzled by the output you get. Edit: also note I'm still using `shift` just specify offset differently.

Comment: interestingly, if your initial date range spans a leap year (try `pd.date_range('1/1/2012', '12/31/2012', freq='D')` for example) and you shift by pd.DateOffset(years = 1), Feb 28 gets duplicated - so still use with caution ;-)

Comment: I use `df['a'] = df['a'].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))` to shift one column, it raises an error: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`, could u help to deal with this issue?